# uploading file object file through angularjs but it is coverted into string, how to receive object file at server end

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am developing a website with `angular.js` and `node.js`, there is a need for upload function in this and I have succeeded in sending the object file from the front end i.e; angular using POST method but when the server receives the file the object file is saved as string file. How do I receive the object file as object file at the server end(node) or how do I convert the string file as object file again?

I have tried sending the file as data and image in the request header and body but it was not successful. The object file received is in the string format

controller:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
vm.getTheFiles = function ($files) {
    alert($files[0]);
    vm.uploadme= $files[0];
    formdata.append('image', $files[0])
    angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
        formdata.append(key, value);
        console.log('fileeeeeeeeeeeeeeee' + key + ' ' + value);
    });
    for (var pair of formdata.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[1]); 
    }
};
vm.uploadFiles = function () {
    console.log(vm.uploadme);

    var request = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/users/upload/',
        data: formdata,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined,
            data: formdata
        }
    };

    // SEND THE FILES.
    $http(request)
    .success(function (d) {
        alert(d);
    })
    .error(function () {
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" fileread="vm.uploadme" ng-files="vm.getTheFiles($files)"  />
<input type="button" ng-click="vm.uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />
```

Node:

```
function upload(req, res) {
   console.log('data',req.headers.data);
   var formdata = req.headers.data;
   var fs = require("fs");
   var filePathFinal1 = '/images/profile/' + formdata + '.png';
   fs.createWriteStream('app' + filePathFinal1);
   res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

In the above node code I receive the display as string but I want the object file as it is.